# Convert "0000" into a lubridate in R

Tags: r, data-conversion, lubridate

What appears simple, is for me quite a brain teaser.
I got this

```
times1 <- c(0000, 0720, 2315, 0600, 1150, NA, 0000)
```

and I want got transform this number in hours and mintues with the hm-function that I get an `lubridate` format.

Thank you very much for your help!
Best wishes,
Robin

Answer (score 0):

Try this option:

```
times1 <- c('0000', '0720', '2315', '0600', '1150', NA, '0000')
ts <- ifelse(is.na(times1),
             NA,
             paste0(substr(times1, 1, 2), ":", substr(times1, 3, 4), ":00"))
x <- hms(ts)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. However, I still get that message: In .parse_hms(..., order = "HMS", quiet = quiet) :
  Some strings failed to parse, or all strings are NAs
Have you ever encountered that problem?

Comment: I just updated my answer, try it again. (Reload your page).

Comment: Thanx for the update. Unfortantly I still get the same error message. Maybe it's something with my time settings?

Comment: I just updated again, I can't test at the moment unfortunately.

Comment: Closer: "0::00"    "72:0:00"  "23:15:00" "60:0:00"  "11:50:00" NA         "0::00"  Nice work with NA!  I'm trying now to get rid of the ::

Comment: You have bad data.  My answer would work if you actually had _strings_.  You may not be able to fix it if you have numbers.  By the way, there is no leading zero in `0720`, it is just `720`.

Answer (score 0):

since your aim is to convert to hours and minutes, you need to use the `hm` function and not the `hms` function:

```
times1 <- c('0000', '0720', '2315', '0600', '1150', NA, '0000')
hm(sub("(\\d{2})","\\1:",times1))
[1] "0S"         "7H 20M 0S"  "23H 15M 0S" "6H 0M 0S"   "11H 50M 0S"
[6] NA           "0S"
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you very much!